# Single API use for authenticated and guest user

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-passport

My laravel application route configured on routes/api.php is.

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
Route::post('see_all_product',  'API\ProductController@see_all_product');
?>
```

Issue is i want to sent list of product but if user authenticated then send  product favorite flag 1, and if not authenticated then send return favorite 0

But both case send product list with favorite flag.

If i logged in with my user id and password and send request for **see_all_product** that time i m getting blank user.

```
$user = $request->user();
```

But if i set route like below i m getting user details.

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
        Route::post('see_all_product',  'API\ProductController@see_all_product');
});
?>
```

Now issue is how can i get details if authorization set in the header with same api.

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
Route::post('see_all_product',  'API\ProductController@see_all_product');
?>
```

My **see_all_product** Function

```
public function see_all_product(Request $request){ 
    try { 
        $user = $request->user(); 
    } catch (Exception $ex) { 
        Log::error($ex); 
    }
}
```

API is same for both authenticated and guest user.

I pass authorization token in both case but middleware route i get user details but non middleware route i dont get user information.

Please guide me where i can miss something?

Comment: paste your controller method `see_all_product` code here

Comment: @SalmanZafar 

Get user details based on below details

```<?php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
        Route::post('see_all_product',  'API\ProductController@see_all_product');
});
?>```

Not Get user details based on below details

```<?php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
Route::post('see_all_product',  'API\ProductController@see_all_product');
?>```

Comment: add this code in your question

Comment: are you making the request from inside laravel or from something like postman ?

Comment: @Cameron post man

Comment: turn off the middleware for auth:api  because it will block guests.
Also are you passing the proper credentials via postman to auth the user?


if(auth('api')->check()){
          //return extra data
} else {
         //return something else
}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can do it by the way instead of `$request->user()`:

```
if (auth('api')->check()) { 
    $user = auth('api')->user();
}
```

Comment: Not working blank user.

if i change my route to this then working but facing issue with non authorized user.
```<?php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
        Route::post('see_all_product',  'API\ProductController@see_all_product');
});
?>```

Comment: Then you have more deeply problem because this should be work on unathorized endpoints. What is your guard and provider? Do you have any specific settings at authentication settings?

Comment: I changed my reply. Do you check and try again like this?

Answer (score 4):

### I didn't test this method on old versions of Laravel, but it should work just fine on the latest ones.

You can create another Middleware that allows ether authenticated or guest users to proceed.

If the user is authenticated then the middleware will prepare the Auth object and auth() function for you.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory as Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AuthOptional
{
    /**
     * The authentication factory instance.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory
     */
    protected $auth;

    /**
     * Create a new middleware instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory  $auth
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Auth $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        $this->authenticate($request, $next, $guards);
        return $next($request);
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the user is logged in to any of the given guards.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  array  $guards
     * @return void
     *
     */
    protected function authenticate($request, $next, array $guards)
    {
        if (empty($guards)) {
            $guards = [null];
        }

        foreach ($guards as $guard) {
            if ($this->auth->guard($guard)->check()) {
                return $this->auth->shouldUse($guard);
            }
        }

        //If unauthenticated allow the user anyway
        $this->unauthenticated($request, $next, $guards);
    }

    /**
     * Handle an unauthenticated user.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  array  $guards
     * @return void
     *
     */
    protected function unauthenticated($request, $next, array $guards)
    {
        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

Import the newly created Middleware under app/Http/kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        ....
        'auth.optional'          => \App\Http\Middleware\AuthOptional::class
    ];
```

And finally use it like this:

```
<?php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth.optional:api']],
        
});
?>
```

> Now auth()->user() will return the user if user is authenticated and
> null if it's not

Comment: i still wondering why laravel doesnt make it by default for apis route! 
but this is the best way to deal with basic laravel auth without using external libraries ..

Answer (score 3):

Turn off `['middleware'=> 'auth:api']`

use: `$request->user('api');` in your `controller`.
`Guests` can use the `api` but user is `null`;

`Auth` users can use `api` as a real user.

alt:

```
Auth::guard('api')->user();

auth('api')->user();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$middlewares = \Request::header('Authorization') ? ['jwt.verify', 'auth:api'] : [];

Route::middleware($middlewares)->group(function () {
    Route::get('/demo/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\Api\DemoController::class,'demoindex']);
});
```

based on others answer on this issue . Looks good use.